# "Низшее" сословие. Нужны ли кавычки при написании слова "низшее"?

Tags: выбор-слов, кавычки

Нужно ли заключать в кавычки слово "низшему" в следующем предложении:

**За всю историю государства лишь однажды недовольному "низшему" сословию удалось сокрушить правящий режим — в октябре 1917-го.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки не нужны. Это общепринятый термин (хотя чаще говорят "низшее сословие"). Процитирую Грамоту.ру о том, в каких случаях требуется употребление кавычек:

> В современном русском языке кавычки выполняют следующие функции:
>
> 1. Выделение безабзацной прямой речи и цитат.
> 2. Выделение условных (собственных) наименований.
> 3. Выделение слов, которые употребляются в необычном, ироническом, особом значении.

В Вашем предложении нет оснований для употребления кавычек. Но если из более широкого контекста можно сделать вывод, что под "нижним сословием" понимается не общепринятое значение, а другое — расширенное (включая прогрессивную часть высших сословий), тогда кавычки нужны.

Upd. После моего ответа в вопросе было изменено "нижнее" на "низшее".

Comment: Подтверждаю сим: не увидел сразу второе — ошибочное "нижнее". Такого сословия не было. Был нижний (средний) класс.

Comment: @shampar Ничего против не имею. Я просто указал в ответе, чтобы моё замечание про "нижнее" не вызывало недоумения :) "Нижнее сословие" тоже встречается в литературе, и я не уверен, что это точно ошибочно, но спорить не стану (под Вашу ответственность :)

Comment: Согласна с Вами в том, что в вопросе надо было оставить слово "нижнее" (такое определение, действительно, иногда встречается). В своём ответе Вы поправляете вопрошающего. Компенсирую пикировку баллами.

Comment: «...в славянских феодальных государствах и в России, где низшие сословия объединялись наименованием "подлых"». (Ленин)

Comment: @shampar Никто не спорит, что есть выражение "низшие сословия" (в ответе же сказано, что оно употребляется чаще). Но встречается и "нижнее". Вопрос в том, есть ли достаточные основания считать последнее безграмотным. Если нет, то должна действовать презумпция правоты автора.

Comment: Но встречается и "нижнее" сословие? Где?

Comment: @shampar Google.books много находит, в том числе в нормальных изданиях. Пример: "Что касается грамотных мещан и нижнего сословия, ..." (Даниил Гранин, "Священный дар"). Я смотрю публикацию в "Новом мире" в 1971 г.

Comment: Это ж писательская публицистика.

Answer (score 1):

Ленин не ставил кавычки:

> Вся наша аграрная программа имеет целью уничтожение крепостнических и сословных традиций в области аграрных отношений, а для такого уничтожения возможно апеллировать единственно **к низшему сословию**, к угнетенным этими остатками крепостного порядка». Ленин. «Ответ Иксу», стр. 29. (Сочинения, 5 изд., том 7, стр. 219—220. Ред.)

Вот еще примеры:

> К услугам иностранок прибегали обеспеченные господа из высших и средних слоев общества, а русские «кабацкие распутные девки» удовлетворяли потребности низшего сословия. [Виталий Колесников. Русский блуд // «Криминальный отдел», 2010]
>
> В разгар войны, в 1916 году, официально разрешили зачислять в летные школы представителей низшего сословия. [Феликс Чуев. Ильюшин (1998)]
>
> Так «крестьяне» были избавлены от «власти помещиков», но остались низшим, неполноправным сословием. [В. А. Маклаков. Из воспоминаний (1954)]

Из [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8):

> По состоянию на начало XX века проживающие в Российской империи разделялись на подданных и иностранцев.
> Подданные в свою очередь делились на природных подданных, инородцев и финляндских обывателей. В свою очередь природные подданные, жители Финляндии, а также некоторые из инородцев разделялись на сословные группы[1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)
> Согласно общим положениям в начале IX тома Свода законов (статья 2) все природные обыватели России предполагались разделёнными на четыре главных группы людей:
> 1.дворяне,
> 2.христианское духовенство,
> 3.городские обыватели,
> 4.сельские обыватели (крестьянство).
> Свод законов называл эти группы **сословиями** (статья 4)

Получается, что низшим сословием являлись крестьяне.
Среди городских обывателей последними в иерархии были рабочие. Часто их тоже   имели в виду, говоря о **низшем сословии** или о **низших сословиях**.

Answer (score 0):

Низший слой населения. Чин низшего, XIV класса. В России к февралю 1917 года утвердилось сословное деление на дворян, духовенство, крестьянство, купечество и мещанство. Разночинцы стояли особняком.

По аналогии с любой иерархией, имеющей высшие слои, ниже находящиеся могли лишь условно называться низшими.

*«...в славянских феодальных государствах и в России, где низшие сословия объединялись наименованием "подлых"». (Ленин)*

Было бы ошибкой только одно из сословий, никогда прежде так не определявшееся, называть низшим (нижним). Поэтому кавычки необходимо оставить.

Comment: "Но встречается и "нижнее" сословие? Где?" Н. В. Гоголь. Мертвые души. Т. 2. Варианты:  _По обеим сторонам его, сняв шапки, шли два человека **нижнего сословия**, — шли, разговаривая и о чем-то с <ним> толкуя._  https://books.google.ee/books?id=PuGPAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT141&lpg=PT141&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=Lwz_2dYl87&sig=mRUNs-rsmbXkebMZV5zER1pHW0Q&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj02bDrrY3ZAhWHY1AKHV3NCZ84FBDoAQgwMAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5&f=false

Comment: Н.В. как писатель мог допускать... Кто же запретит. И автор фразы из вопроса, если она не из реферата по истории, тоже может.

Comment: Нет, это не реферат. Это предложение из статьи журнала, который скоро выйдет в свет. Кавычки я сняла. Все комментарии внимательно прочитала, все точки зрения учла. Всем большое спасибо!